# beamer: three figs<+-> side-by-side, coordinated with itemize<+->

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

In a `beamer` slide using overlays, I want two show three items in an `itemize` environment sequentially, and have a corresponding figure appear, respectively, left, center and right.

In my MWE, below, I use three `minipage`s separated by `\hfill` for the figures and that causes the middle figure to jump around.  How can I get the second, `<2->` figure to stay in the same position as for slide `<3->` ?

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{beamer} 
\usepackage{mwe} % <-- for dummy images

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Plots: Data, Model, Data + Model}
  Example: Linear model--- Prestige $\sim$ Income + Education + Type
  \begin{itemize*}
    \item <1->Data plot:  \alert{marginal} relation of Income on Prestige
    \item <2->Model (effect) plot: \alert{conditional} fitted values, controlling for other variables 
    \item <3->Data + Model plot: Effect of Income (model) + \alert{partial residuals} (data)
  \end{itemize*}

    \vspace{1ex}

  % three figs side-by-side
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics<1->[width=1\linewidth,clip]{example-image-a}
     \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics<2->[width=1\linewidth,clip]{example-image-b}
     \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics<3->[width=1\linewidth,clip]{example-image-c}
    \end{minipage}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `\phantom`ized third image on slides one and two:

```
\documentclass[10pt,table]{beamer} 
\usepackage{mwe} % <-- for dummy images

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Plots: Data, Model, Data + Model}
  Example: Linear model--- Prestige $\sim$ Income + Education + Type
  \begin{itemize}
    \item <1->Data plot:  \alert{marginal} relation of Income on Prestige
    \item <2->Model (effect) plot: \alert{conditional} fitted values, controlling for other variables 
    \item <3->Data + Model plot: Effect of Income (model) + \alert{partial residuals} (data)
  \end{itemize}

    \vspace{1ex}

  % three figs side-by-side
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics<1->[width=1\linewidth,clip]{example-image-a}
     \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics<2->[width=1\linewidth,clip]{example-image-b}
     \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \alt<3>{%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.33\textwidth}
     \includegraphics<3->[width=1\linewidth,clip]{example-image-c}
    \end{minipage}}{%
    \begin{minipage}[c]{.33\textwidth}
     \phantom{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,clip]{example-image-c}}
    \end{minipage}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

An animation of the result:

[image]

Comment: That is perfect!  I didn't know about `\alt<>{}{}`.  I especially appreciate your showing it as an animation, and this may be helpful to others.